# Suppose that all functions ${f_n},f$ are integrable. Is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n(x)dx = \int f(x)dx?$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of continuous, strictly positive functions on $\mathbb{R}$ which converges uniformly to the function $f.$ Suppose that all the functions ${f_n},f$ are integrable. Is
>   $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n(x)dx = \int f(x)dx\ ?$$

This is clearly true if on an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ because then there is $k$ and $\epsilon$ such that $f_k$ and $\epsilon$ which dominates the other $f_n$.  Any suggestions?  Thanks (Its a qual problem from a previous exam)

Comment: Have a look at the dominated convergence theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Comment: This works on bounded intervals for sure. What is your notion of uniform convergence over an unbounded set? Is it uniform convergence on all compact sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nope. let's get rid of the assumption 'strictly' positive - we'll just add our nonnegative functions to a strictly positive and integrable functions of your choice $f$. the point is to make $\int f_n dx$ divergent. what we do is we let 
$$f_n := f + \frac{1}{n}\chi_{[0, n^2]}$$
where $\chi$ is the characteristic function. obviously the integrals get bigger and diverge to infinity while we still have uniform convergence, since $||f - f_n||_{\infty} = 1/n$

edit: sorry, to preserve continuity just add something nicer than the characteristic function - it's easy to 'smooth' it out, but the general idea stays the same

Comment: Take e.g.

$$
f_{n}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x}{n^{2}}, & x\in\left[0,n\right]\\
\frac{1}{n}\left(2-\frac{x}{n}\right), & x\in\left[n,2n\right]\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$ and add a strictly positive, integrable function (as you already pointed out).

Comment: If you were to add $\frac{1}{n^2}\chi_{[0,n^3]}$ you would not need to comment on negatives...